# how to make large integer arrays (40 digit integers)

Tags: c++

I got an assignment:

**HugeInteger Class** 
Create a class HugeInteger that uses a 40-element array of digits to store integers as large as 40 digits each

The problem is that int can only have up to 5 digits, float up to 7 sigits and double up to 15 digits. So my question is how do I allow the user to enter 40 digits into an array?

I was thinking of using pointers but I don't really have much experience with pointers. I think that instead of allowing longer digit inputs the pointer would go for the next element in the array.

Comment: i am new to c++ and as i said in my ques i have to enter 40 digit integers in one array iteration ( like  a[5] to have 40 digit integers i do believe that using a pointer will allow me only upto 5 digits(~65000) and then the pointer will go for a[6]

Comment: I think you misunderstand the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution is an array (of `char` etc.) with one element per digit.
Ie. you could tore the number as printable string (ACII digits),
or real numeric values in the `char`´s (more difficult input/output,
all other things easier)
You could also store 2 digits per `char` (better memory usage, but more complicated)...

In any case, with a solution like that,
you´ll have to implement how calculations like `+ - * /` work with your integer type.
The computer can´t do it like with built-in types.

(A 32bit integer can store 9 or 10 decimal digits (depending on the value), not 5.
Are you on a 16bit system?)